# How can i download a file created in an old app in my new Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel

There are two applications, an old one written in raw php and a new one in Laravel 6.

The old one generates a File using dabatase data and i want to know if there is a chance that i can run that function in my laravel app so i don't have to rewrite that function all over again.

The two apps are in the same server.
Should i copy the code of the old app in a Laravel Controller and run it there?, or maybe build an API.

Thanks

Comment: You should rewrite it for laravel, it will be good practice and you can make the code cleaner and smaller by using laravel's inbuilt tools.

Comment: As @Piyush mentioned you should rewrite your old code according to recommended best practices for your current framework. You surely can inherit (copy) some or most of your original code, but this exercise allows you to 
a) revise your code and make sure there is no dead wood left, b) avoid compatibility issues in future. Otherwise you will probably spend event more time making some crunchy import of old code which will sooner or later fail and that will happen in most critical time (it always does).

Answer (score 1):

**Quick answer**: don't paste legacy PHP code in a Laravel controller.

Since you have decided to start a new Laravel 6 application, you should try to stick with the Laravel way (and modern PHP coding standards), and therefore rewritte your old legacy code from scratch into your new Laravel app.

There is no shortcut for that, and it might take time, but not only will it last longer in time and be more efficient than the legacy code, it will also help you learn new coding standards.

Here is an article that can help you getting started: [How to rewrite a legacy PHP application to Laravel.](https://oliverlundquist.com/2018/12/22/how-to-rewrite-a-legacy-php-app-to-laravel.html)

If what the old code does is just getting rows from the database and exporting it into a file, that should be fairly simple thanks to Laravel and a composer package like [maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)

You can find many articles on Google on [How to Export Mysql Data to Excel File in Laravel](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/05/how-to-export-mysql-data-to-excel-file-in-laravel.html)